# Proving a graph is connected

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

I have to prove that if a graph G=(V,E) has |V|=2n and every vertex has a degree of n, (with n<-N*) then it is connected.

I have this so far:

If there are 2n verticles and each one has a degree of n, then the number of connections is n^2.

We know there is no vertex with 0 degree, so if G is not connected, then it consists of at least 2 connected graphs, and all of their verticles also have a degree of n.

How do i continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the graph is not connected, say the vertex set is partitioned into $V_1$, $V_2$ such that between them there is no edge, then $V_1$ must have at least $n+1$ vertices, so does $V_2$, contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!
Shouldnt i also assume that there could be more than 2 components?

Comment: If there are $k$ components, then see $V_1$ as the first $k-1$ components, and the rest is $V_2$.

Comment: Got it now.
Thanks again!